# Error on deploying web application on tomcat 8 - No suitable driver

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, maven, tomcat8

i have a web application on Debian 8 / Eclipse Mars / Maven 3.3.3. All maven dependencies are ok but on lancing tomcat 8, the JDBC (postgresql) can not be found.

Where Tomcat 8 is looking for retrieve the dependencies (in which folder)?

Here is my stack

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.connection(SessionImpl.java:427)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:450)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.postgresql.Driver' for connect URL '${database.url}'
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2160)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2032)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1532)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2151)
    ... 19 more
```

My pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    ....
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Testing see https://opencast.jira.com/wiki/display/MH/Unit+Testing+REST+Endpoints -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.catch-exception</groupId>
            <artifactId>catch-exception</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.catch-exception</groupId>
            <artifactId>catch-throwable</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Reading & Writing CSV -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Database -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>9.3-1100-jdbc4</version> -->
            <version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Gestion de transactions par aspects. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Serialization JSON -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
            <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Manipulation de données -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Google Collections Library & Basics Features -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>15.0</version>
            <classifier>cdi1.0</classifier>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Groovy : execution de scripts sur les match rules -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Selenium -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId> <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId> 
            <version>2.33.0</version> </dependency> -->

        <!-- Restlet -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Permet de jouer avec les entêtes HTTP Inutile (à priori a partir de 
            Tomcat 7.0.41+ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Librairie ehcache-probe est utilisée pour monitorer ehcache.
         -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>fakepath</groupId>
          <artifactId>ehcache-probe</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
            <artifactId>usertype.extended</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    ....
</project>
```

Comment: where is properties 'database.url' ?

Comment: The 'database.url' is in context.xml (META-INF/context.xml)